# How to use standard pipeline (tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma) with the new parsers?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have been using an older version of Stanford NLP, but would like to switch to the newest, coolest algorithms. However I looked at the demo of the NN dependecy parser and I don't know how to integrate it with the CoreNLP pipeline.

I was using this jython code:

```
props = Properties()
props.put("annotators","tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse")
props.put("isOneSentence",True)
pipeline = StanfordCoreNLP(props)
```

But now I'd like to use the newer algorithms. Is this possible with the current pipeline? If not, what is an easy way to rewrite this, so it produces the same results without the annotation pipeline?

Thanks in advance!
Pavel

Answer (score 3):

The annotator you're looking for is "depparse", not "parse". So, the code would look like:

```
props = Properties()
props.put("annotators","tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse")
props.put("isOneSentence",True)
pipeline = StanfordCoreNLP(props)
```

Note that you will no longer have constituency trees (`Tree`) after this, only the dependency tree (`SemanticGraph`).

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot! But I also want to get new constituencies from the shift-reduce parser sometimes. The "parse" annotator now uses this instead of the Lexicalized PCFG?

Comment: So it seems I can use both the nn-dep parser and constituence parser like this:  

    props.put("annotators","tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,depparse")

However there are two questions here:  

1. Does the NN parser really kick in, or are we getting results from LPCFG?  
2. The LPCGF is the old slow implementation, the advertised one is shift-reduce parser that should work much faster. Is there are way to use that parser? Preferably integrated into this annotation pipeline?

Thank you very much,
Pavel

Comment: Yes, in this case the dependency parse will overwrite the constituency parse. You can use the shift reduce constituency parser by following the instructions here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to use two different pipelines, possibly with different .jars, since it seems like NN parser and shift-reduce parser live in separate jars. Its a decent workaround, the speed won't be effected, but the code with one pipeline surely would look nicer!

Comment: They should certainly be in the same CoreNLP jar. The models are in separate jars, but that's just because the shift reduce constituency parser has very large models.